# Simple MIPS error relating to div, $HI, and a branch statement

Tags: branch, mips, division, cpu-registers

I'm trying to replicate the following C code in MIPS:

```c
//sum, n and added are integers and have already been initialized
if(n%3 == 0){
    sum = sum + n;    
    added = added + 1;
}
```

Here is what I *tried* doing.

```mips
#Let t0 = n
#Let s0 = sum
#Let a0 = added
#All have been set earlier in the program

addi $t1, $zero, 3    #Let t1 = 3 for division
div $t0, $t1          #Remainder will be stored in $HI
bne $HI, $zero, ENDIF #skip to ENDIF when remainder != 0; same as if(n%3 == 0)
    add $s0, $s0, $t0
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
ENDIF:
```

When I run it in my MIPS simulator (I'm using QtSpim), I get a compiler error on the if statement.  It reads:

```
bne $HI, $zero, ENDIF #skip to ENDIF when remainder != 0; same as if(n%3 == 0)
     ^
```

What is wrong with the statement, exactly?  I can see that the ^ is under $HI.  Is something wrong with my div statement, causing the error in $HI? Or can $HI not be used in a branch like that? Will I need to move $HI into a temporary register?  Or is something wrong with the branch statement anyway?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to move `$HI` into a register (MIPS branch instructions compare registers).

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the HI register directly, use `mfhi` to get the value in it.

```mips
#Let t0 = n
#Let s0 = sum
#Let a0 = added
#All have been set earlier in the program

addi $t1, $zero, 3    #Let t1 = 3 for division
div $t0, $t1          #Remainder will be stored in $HI
mfhi $t2          #Store the value from $HI in $t0
bne $t2, $zero, ENDIF #skip to ENDIF when remainder != 0; same as if(n%3 == 0)
    add $s0, $s0, $t0
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
ENDIF:
```